# Can I call a function from a div and have it return multiple attributes?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a function to return 2 attributes into the HTML element after it receives an variable from props.

```
<div splitValue(propValue) .../>
```

And it should return

```
<div splitted-value1='val1' splitted-value2='val2' .../>
```

Comment: No, you can't put JavaScript function calls in HTML tags.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't put JS function calls inside HTML. You can use JS to create the HTML:

```
<script>
document.write(`<div ${splitValue(propValue)} ...></div>`);
</script>
```